# Cannot provide equal timestamp value into time.Time variable when unit testing gorm

Tags: unit-testing, go, mocking, go-gorm, datadog

I attempt to write unit tests. Everything was fine until the moment when I started dealing with the time package.

```
"testing"

"github.com/DATA-DOG/go-sqlmock"
"github.com/stretchr/testify/require"
"gorm.io/driver/postgres"
"gorm.io/gorm"
```

```
func createDB(t *testing.T) (*DB, sqlmock.Sqlmock) {
    db, mock, err := sqlmock.New()
    require.NoError(t, err)
    require.NotNil(t, db)
    require.NotNil(t, mock)

    dialector := postgres.New(postgres.Config{
        DSN:                  "sqlmock_db_0",
        DriverName:           "postgres",
        Conn:                 db,
        PreferSimpleProtocol: true,
    })

    gormDB, err := gorm.Open(dialector, &gorm.Config{})
    require.NoError(t, err)
    require.NotNil(t, gormDB)

    return &DB{
        gorm: gormDB,
        db:   db,
    }, mock
}
```

```
func (db *DB) CreateUser(ctx context.Context, user model.User) error {
    err := db.gorm.Create(&user).Error
    return err
}
```

```
timeTest, _ := time.Parse("2006-01-02", "2021-01-14")

sourceUser := models.User{
     CreatedAt: timeTest,
     UpdatedAt: null.NewTime(timeTest, true),
 }
db, mock := createDB(t)
mock.MatchExpectationsInOrder(false)
mock.ExpectBegin()
mock.ExpectExec(regexp.QuoteMeta(`INSERT INTO "user" ("created_at","updated_at") VALUES ($1,$2) RETURNING "id"`)).
 WithArgs(
     sourceUser.CreatedAt,
     sourceUser.UpdatedAt,
     ).WillReturnResult(sqlmock.NewResult(sourceUser.ID, 1))
mock.ExpectCommit()
err := db.CreateUser(context.Background(), &sourceUser)

require.NoError(t, err)
```

> Error:        Received unexpected error:
> call to Query 'INSERT INTO "user" ("created_at","updated_at") VALUES ($1,$2) RETURNING
> "id"' with args [{Name: Ordinal:1 Value:2021-01-14 00:00:00 +0000 UTC}{Name: Ordinal:2 Value:2021-01-14 00:00:00 +0000 UTC}
> ] was not expected; call to Rollback transaction was not expected
>
> INSERT INTO "user" ("created_at","updated_at") VALUES ('2021-01-14 00:00:00','2021-01-14 00:00:00')
> RETURNING "id"

Vars **2021-01-14 00:00:00** and **2021-01-14 00:00:00 +0000 UTC** are not the same.
I try to solve this issue in different ways, but I can't find right.
It is also not working if I edit my QuoteMeta like 'INSERT'

Comment: Not sure if this works for Postgres or will help you in general, but did you stumble on the ParseTime initialisation string for GORM? https://learningprogramming.net/golang/gorm/date-in-gorm/